# use generic type in decorator

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I would like to create exception filters for my NestJs application. I basically took code from here

https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters#exception-filters-1

and created my own version

```
import { ExceptionFilter, Catch } from '@nestjs/common';

@Catch(TException)
export class BaseExceptionFilter<TException extends Error> implements ExceptionFilter {
  catch(exception: TException): void {
    // ...
  }
}
```

This exception filter should run basic logic and takes a generic of type `Error`. The `Catch` decorator can't deal with that generic type

> Cannot find name 'TException'. Did you mean 'DOMException'?ts(2552)

Is it possible to use that generic outside from the class definition? Because basically I can pass in any type I want

```
@Catch(String)
export class BaseExceptionFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
  catch(exception: string): void {
    // ...
  }
}
```

but I think it has to exist before runtime ... any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Would you mind me asking what your use-case is?

Comment: Sure :) In my NestJs app I have custom exceptions for the service layer. And NestJs provides premade HttpExceptions. With that generic exception filter I want to create a base class for mapping. So I'm passing in custom exception and map it to the HttpException

Comment: replace the generic with an interface?

Comment: @bashleigh would you mind providing an example?

Comment: The catch decorator take a class as argument, so your custom exception must be a class and you other exception must extends this TException, but you can't use a generic inside this decorator.